# I want to use Bilinear interpolation to calculate the summation of vectors

Tags: arrays, image-processing, vector, computer-vision, interpolation

I have individual vectors from my last stage of code which i implemented it
The next stage of the algorithm is to calculate the summation of these vectors 
As mentioned in the paper

"The vectors from the previous stage were summed together spatially by 
 bilinearly weighting"

I think The bilinear weighting means bilinear interpolation

can any one tell or give me an example how can i use bilinear interpolation

to calculate the Summation of this vectors

V1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2]

V2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 11]

V3 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23, 0, 0]

V4 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 19, 19, 0, 0]

V5 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0]

V6 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 0, 0]

V7 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18, 18, 0, 0]

V8 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 23, 23, 0, 0, 0]

V9= [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]

V10 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0]

V11 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 8, 0, 0]

V12 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 11, 0, 0, 0]

V13 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

V14 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]

V15 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0]

V16 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0]
I googled it but didn't understand the Equations

Regards  and thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you link to a copy of this paper? Bilinear interpolation is used when to interpolate between points in a function with two inputs. Is the above image supposed to represent a 2D function or matrix of some kind, or is it just a series of vectors?

Comment: I don't see how bilinear interpolation can be used to sum up a vector.  As what eigenchris said, it is a methodology use for 2D signals so that you can interpolate in between points.  A vector is inherently 1D.

Comment: You would also have a higher change of getting a useful answer if you pasted the values rather than include an image of the values.

Comment: @eigenchris it just a series of vectors

Comment: @eigenchris

http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~olga/Courses/Fall2014/CS9840/PossibleStudentPapers/pami2010.pdf

page 5 section C.[S1]

Thanks eigenchris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly I'm having trouble understanding the paper as well. The idea, as you've said, is to weight the vectors based on their distance from the pooling centres, so that vectors farther from the pooling centres have less of an impact. The paper compares this to what is done in the famous SIFT feature, which you can read about [in this tutorial.](http://www.aishack.in/tutorials/sift-scale-invariant-feature-transform-features/)

Below is by best guess as to what the meaning is. Since this is related to machine learning, could also ask people over at [cross-validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) to get their opinion, or consider contacting the author of the paper.

---

If I understand correctly, this is amounts to a process similar to bilinear interpolation, except in reverse.

With bilinear interpolation, we are given a set of function values arranged in a grid, and we want to find a good guess for what the function values are between the gridpoints. We do this by taking a weighted average of the four surrounding function values, with the weights being the relative area of the **opposite** rectangle in the image below. (By "relative" I mean the area is normalized by the area of the whole grid rectangle, so the weights sum to 1.)  Note how the point to be interpolated is the closest to the `(x1,y2)` gridpoint, so we weight it with the largest weight (the relative area of the yellow rectangle).

`f(x,y) = w_11*f(x1,y1) + w_21*f(x2,y1) + w_12*f(x1,y2) + w_22*f(x2,y2)`

`w_ij = area of rectangle opposite (xi,yj) / total area of grid square`

[image]

The "bilinear weighing" described in the paper seems to be doing the opposite: we have values (or vectors in this case) scattered throughout 2D space, and we want to "pool" their values at a set of gridpoints that we choose.

We do this by adding a fraction of each vector to the four surrounding pooling gridpoints. This fraction would again be the relative area of the opposite rectangle.

In the above image... pooling point `(xi,yj)` would get `w_ij * f(x,y)` summed along with the appropriate fraction of any other points we have in the region.

As the paper states, the spacing of the grid points is up to you. I assume it would need to be big enough to allow most polling points have at least one vector in its neighbourhood.

---

**EDIT**: Here is an example of what I mean.

```
(0,1) . _ _ _ _ _ . (1,1)
      |           |
      |   v       |
      |           |
      |           |
(0,0) . _ _ _ _ _ . (1,0)
```

Let's say the vector `v=[10,5]` is at point `(0.2,0.8)`

point `(0,0)` gets weight `0.8*0.2=0.16`, so we add `0.16*v = [1.6,0.8]` to that pool
point `(1,0)` gets weight `0.2*0.2=0.04`, so we add `0.04*v = [0.4,0.2]` to that pool
point `(0,1)` gets weight `0.8*0.8=0.64`, so we add `0.64*v = [6.4,3.2]` to that pool
point `(1,1)` gets weight `0.2*0.8=0.16`, so we add `0.16*v = [1.6,0.8]` to that pool

Comment: This answer was more than what the OP deserved. +1.  Also love the graphical illustrations.

Comment: Really many thanks eigenchris for your help !
You cleared up many misunderstanding points

Comment: @eigenchris 
I just need numerical example to understand more using my vectors :) 
Could you clear it little bit to me if you don't mind ?
Regards !